# UploadBase.php setting to save SVG file on mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I'am using an addon on my wiki, to edit svg files on the fly: but now I had this problem; A user copy and paste a diagram from drawio and try to pase on the wiki and this error appears:

```
The wiki returned the following error when uploading: Found href to unsafe data: URI target"" in the uploaded SVG file.
```

How can I avoid this in my `UploadBase.php` last time the URI got an url on the target (the url was http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml), so I did this:

```
static $validNamespaces = [
                        'adobe:ns:meta/',
                        'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
```

And this worked just fine: but what about an empty one?